# How to add names to layers of Keras sequential model

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I use Keras in Tensorflow 2.0 to create a sequential model:

```
def create_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28), name="bla"),
        keras.layers.Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(REGULARIZE), activation="relu",),
        keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT_RATE),
        keras.layers.Dense(128, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(REGULARIZE), activation="relu"),
        keras.layers.Dropout(DROPOUT_RATE),
        keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer="adam",
                  loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                  metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

model = create_model()

# Checkpoint callback
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True)

# Train model
model.fit(train_images,
          train_labels,
          epochs=EPOCHS,
          callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

If I extract the names after loading the model in separate file I get the following:

```
# Create model instance
model = create_model()

# Load  weights of pre-trained model
model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)

output_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]
print(output_names) = ['flatten', 'dense', 'dropout', 'dense_1', 'dropout_1', 'dense_2']
```

In this case, I would expect `bla` instead of `flatten`.

How can I add custom names to my layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it the right way, straight from my jupyter :

```py
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28), name="bla"),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu",),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam",
              loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["accuracy"])
model
```

> tensorflow.python.keras.engine.sequential.Sequential at 0x2b6ecf083c18>

```
output_names = [layer.name for layer in model.layers]
output_names
```

> ['bla', 'dense', 'dropout', 'dense_1', 'dropout_1', 'dense_2']

Edit adding the load/save part :

```py
model.save('my_model.h5')
second_model =  keras.models.load_model('my_model.h5')
output_names = [layer.name for layer in second_model.layers]
output_names
```

> ['bla', 'dense', 'dropout', 'dense_1', 'dropout_1', 'dense_2']

Can you add your whole code, the problem may lie elsewhere.

Also can you add your tensorflow version?

Comment: Do I  have to reset my model? Is there a command for that? I use PyCharm and Tensorflow 2.0.

Comment: You don't have to reset your code, as far as you have use a `model.save` and `keras.models.load_model` you're good to go

Comment: `cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True)` you put save_weights only, then it won't add the layers name, put it to `False`